# Minimal degree representation of finite simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

For this question I am taking a *representation* of a group $G$ to be a homomorphism from $G$ to $GL_n(K)$ for some field $K$. The *degree* of the representation is $n$.

I am trying to understand the minimal degree of a nontrivial representation for nonabelian finite simple groups. So suppose I define $f(n)$ to be the minimum of the degrees of nontrivial representations of all nonabelian finite simple groups of size at least $n$.

Is there some kind of asymptotic description of $f(n)$? Does any meaningful asymptotic information about $f(n)$ rely on the classification of finite simple groups?

Comment: I believe that the minimal degree representations of the finite simple groups over fields are well understood, so it should be possible to answer this question. This does depend on CFSG. Without thinking about it much I would guess that in characteristic $0$, the degree $n-1$ representations of $A_n$ have the smallest degree with respect to the order of the group.